# htaccess help - change domain and remove segments

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've changed the domain and url structure of a site I have been working on.

How do I 301 redirect all requests from the below old structure to the new structure? Also note the new structure doesn't have the trailing slash.

OLD: `http://www.domain.me/2017/01/30/entry-title/`

---- 301 redirect to below --->

NEW: `http://www.newdomain.com/entry-title`

This is what I have tried so far: `RewriteRule /\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*) $1 [R=301, L]`

Many thanks

Update: htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

#entry pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/([^/]+)/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

#other
RewriteRule ^shop/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/shop" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^shop-wish-list-2017/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/shop" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-me/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/about" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/about" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/dubai/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/category/dubai" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/travel/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/category/travel" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/health/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/category/lifestyle" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/beauty/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/category/fashion-beauty" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/lifestyle/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/category/lifestyle" [R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fairly close. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/([^/]+)/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

- `^/?` makes leading slash options so that rule works from Apache config as well from .htaccess
- `/?$` makes trailing slash optional so that we can discard it in target `/$1`

Make this rule is first rule after `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Sorry a little bit of confusion probably on my part, where do I add the new domain in that rule? So all requests go to the new domain with the new structure? Thanks

Comment: So that it sends all old domain requests to the new domain, with the new structure as you have done above..

Comment: Apologies, I have only just been able to re-visit this. It's not working when the first domain has a trailing slash e.g. http://domain.me/2222/33/33/entry-title/. if i remove it it works perfect..

Comment: I already have `/?$` in my rule to make trailing rule optional. Make sure this rule is placed as first rule below `RewriteEngine` line and then retest in a new browser.

Comment: Yep i have tried in a few browsers with the same result.. I have updated my question with my whole .htaccess if that helps..

Comment: Your .htaccess looks good and strips off trailing `/` after redirect on my Apache. You might still have bad browser cache. Try to test using a command line `curl` or `wget` or else completely clear browser cache.

Comment: "and strips off trailing / after redirect" I just want to check, this htaccess is on the old domain server correct? Sending all requests to the new server+ domain, how can it strip it after redirection? DO I need to place this on the new server?

Comment: No, this rule must be placed on old domain itself.